# Downloading multiple files with low bandwidth

Tags: download-manager, connection-speed

What software is there for downloading (over HTTP) multiple files with unreliable slow internet connection?

It should be able to keep tracks of several pending downloads and resume them upon request, without re-downloading.

Then it should check the hash sum to make sure the download was successful or else inform if it wasn't.

Ideally a simple free tool for Mac OS or command line.

Comment: There are many downloaders supporting "resume". Do you want them to keep track automatically – or is it fine if they simply "fail" when the connection "drops" and you'd have to trigger the resume manually? Any preferences concerning the queue setup (e.g. "load from file", "give one-at-a-time per command-line", or "must have GUI")? I'm not a Mac user, but [iGetter](http://www.igetter.net/iGetter.html) might be worth a look (first hit on [Google `http downloader mac-os resume`](https://www.google.com/search?q=http+downloader+mac-os+resume), by the way :)

Comment: Oh, also worth reading: [Best Mac Tips: How to resume pretty much any download that fails](http://best-mac-tips.com/2012/02/05/resuming-broken-downloads/) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot check it out myself (I'm not a MacOS user), bit **[iGetter](http://www.igetter.net/iGetter.html)** seems to be what you're after:

> iGetter is a powerful, full featured download manager and accelerator. iGetter can greatly improve the speed of your downloads using segmented downloading. In addition it allows auto resume on broken downloads, queue filtering by various criteria, site explorer, history list, scheduling downloads for low traffic periods, auto redial on broken connection, auto hang-up and shut down on completion, and much more.

- **supports resume:** Yes, even automatically. But as with any such tools, servers must support this as well (if a server doesn't, *iGetter* will inform you on the fact)
- **check whether download was successful:** That's part of the resume process :)

Additional features of interest:

- supports multiple sources ("mirrors") for the same file to speed up downloading ("download accelerator", "segmented downloading")
- a nice GUI lets you follow the progress and organize your downloads
- scheduled downloads: tell it when to go for it :)
- site explorer to investigate remote ftp or http sites

[image: scheduler] [image: manage downloads] [image: segmented downloading]
<sup>*iGetter* screenshots: scheduler, download manager, segmented downloading (source: [iGetter](http://www.igetter.net/iGetter.html); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: This awesome! Downloaded 50MB like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: Always glad to help! And amazed what a little Google-Fu sometimes brings up :) Enjoy!

Comment: Yes, Google-Fu works great when you know the right "Fu" :)